# Index is multiplicative

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and satisfies minimal condition on subnormal subgroups. Further let $H, K\trianglelefteq G$, such that $H\leq K$ and $[G:H]$ is finte, then can we say something about $[G:K]$ ?. That whether  $[G:K]$ it would be finite or not?

Comment: You don't need any hypotheses on $G$, nor do you need any normality hypotheses on $H$ or $K$.

Answer (score 0):

$$[G:H]=[G:K][K:H].$$
If $[G:H]$ finite, then $[G:K]$ is finite and divide $[G:H]$.